# I am stuck in a problem related to Bootstrap, where i have to create a webpage for small devices and divide them in 1:4:1 format but cant get it ryt

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

> column 1 and column 3(left and right cols) have passed the test case
> but not column 2 ( the middle one) that i  have commented in the code.
> Please help
> thank you
>
> The problem has the following conditions i cannot add images rn which would have made thge process more easier.i can provide image tho in other way.

> Note: Some part of the web page is already been created.  You have to write the code only for the part (for column1, column 2, column3 and footer except the text content) which is mentioned in the template

Key Points:

1. ```
     Create a three column layouts for the web page for small devices.
   ```
2. ```
     Layout should contain a row with three columns divided in 1:4:1 ratio for the small devices.
   ```
3. ```
     Column 1 and 3 should belong to the side navigation class of <div> with the id ‘’col1’ and ‘col3’. set the class as: 'col-sm-2' and 'sidenav' respectively. (classes should be in the same order specified.)
   ```
4. ```
     In column 2, the text should be left-aligned, use appropriate class for the div with id ‘col2’.
   ```
5. ```
     The footer should be a Bootstrap fluid container with centered text.
   ```

   ```
            <h4> Our Branches </h4>
            <br>
                <p>394 SW. Courtland Drive
            Egg Harbor Township, NJ 08234
            </p><br><br>
                <p>76 East Middle River Street
            Methuen, MA 01844</p>
            </div>

          </div>


            <!-- **THIS PART IS GIVING ME TROUBLE TAKE A LOOK**


               **<div class="col-sm-8" id="col2">
                  <div class="col-lg-8 text-left">


              <h1>Welcome</h1>
              <p>text i removed the text so that code don't look that lenghty----------------- 
                 ------ </p>

              <hr>

            <img class="col-md-offset-2" src="img3.png" alt="3" />
            </div>
            </div>**

           -->  

            <div class="col-sm-2  sidenav" id="col3">

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <h4>Categories</h4>
            <div class="well">
                <a href="#">Advice from Our Experts</a>
            </div>

            <div class="well">
                <a href="#"> Our Blogs</a>
            </div>

           </div>       

         </div>
         </div>
         </div>

           <footer class="container-fluid text-center">

           <p>Text placeholders courtesy of <a href="http://www.trinqet.com/">The TrinQet Inc. 
             </a></p>
            </footer>`
    </body>
   ```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#nesting

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to divide 3 columns in ratio of 1:4:1. Now as it is required to make **col1** and **col3** as  `"col-sm-2"`, the ratio **2:8:2** is still equivalent for the above. Therefore the middle column will be `"col-sm-8"`.

Answer (score 0):

use one div tag only instead of two

this will work definitely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).